# Covering chessboard with L-tetrominoes

Tags: combinatorics

Consider an *n x n* chessboard with all 4 corner squares removed. Prove that if the board can be covered with *L*-tetrominoes then *n*-2 is a multiple of 4. Is the converse true? (an L-tetromino is a plane figure shown below, constructed from four unit squares arranged in the form of L)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** By counting the number of squares, $n$ is even.

**Hint:** By using the standard coloring of $i+j \pmod{4}$ for square $(i,j)$, show that $n \neq 4k$.

Hence $n= 4k+2$.

---

I'm not certain about the converse.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use your hints to solve the problem

Comment: @Jebediah How many squares are there in a $n\times n$ chessboard with 4 removed? How many squares are covered by an integer number of $L-$tetrominoes? Hence, show that $n$ is even.

Comment: There are $n^2 - 4$ squares after the removal. An L-tetromino covers a multiple of 4 squares per block.

Comment: @Jebediah Great. Do you see why that shows that $n^2-4$ must be a multiple of 4, and hence $n$ is even?

Comment: I don't see why $n^2-4$ must be a multiple of 4. Care to explain?

Comment: @Jebediah Say that $k$ $L-$treminos were used. How many squares do they cover? This must be equal to the number of squares on the board. This is known as the [technique of double counting](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/double-counting/).

Comment: The tetrominoes must cover 4k squares which is equal to the number of squares on the board. What I'm saying is that I don't know where to go from there.